# Using Yahoo Pipes, how can I do the equivalent of "Loop: assign first two"?

Tags: yahoo-pipes

The Loop operator in Yahoo pipes has two choices for its output: 
Emit (first/all) results, and Assign (first/all) results to *_*.

What I really need is a Loop that will Assign the first TWO results to an element.  Is there any way to accomplish this?

Background: I've got a CSV file, where column 1 is the feed URL and column 2 is an internal feed id.  I start with "Fetch CSV", and connect that to "Loop" inside which I "Fetch Feed" and Assign All Results to item.feed.  That outputs close to what I need, but since some of the feeds in my list are huge and I only display the first two elements of each feed, I want to eliminate the unused data in my output JSON file.

Sounds like it should be easy, right?  But I can't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I finally figured this out.  Created a new Pipe called Truncate2 which pipes "Fetch Feed" into "Truncate" and outputs the result.  I wired "URL Input" into Fetch Feed as the url source, and then from the original Pipe, I pulled Truncate2 inside the Loop and Assigned all results.